# Require_once functionality Working

Tags: php, path, require-once

So, I have a directory structure like this:

```
include/
scripts/
contact.css
contactform.php
ReadMe.txt
show-captcha.php
thank-you.php
```

In the `show_captcha.php` file the following is added to include PHP file from the `/include` subdirectory.

```
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
```

Thise code works perfectly.

My question here is shouldn't it be like this:

```
require_once("include/fgcontactform.php");
```

Without the `./` prefix? What is the meaning of this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

```
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
```

and

```
require_once("include/fgcontactform.php");
```

mostly do the same thing.

The '.' indicates the current working directory.

Comment: These two statements don't necessarily "do the same thing". It is possible, on another system perhaps, that these statements include different files. In the second example, that uses a _relative_ file path, PHP will first search the `include_path`. Whereas the first example (with the `./` prefix) is always relative to the _current working directory_ (CWD) which could even be changed during script execution.

Answer (score 0):

`./include/fgcontactform.php` means you're including from current working directory.

When your requirement is to include from other directory you do something like this -

`../PATH_TO_DIRECTORY/include/fgcontactform.php`